# How to make my linq to entities query for sum faster

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

What is the most efficient way to go from `MediaPlanBillingDetails` to `MediaPlanPrint` and calculate Sum of Amount RoId wise? Basically MediaPlanBillingDetails is the base table.

Current Query:

```
var sumofallbills= MediaPlanBillingDetails.Sum(m => m.MediaPlanRO.MediaPlanROPrints.Sum(qq => qq.MediaPlanPrint.Amount));
```

Example Data:

```
 var aS = new List<MediaPlanBillingDetails>();
        aS.Add(new MediaPlanBillingDetails { BillId = 1, RoID = 1 });
        aS.Add(new MediaPlanBillingDetails { BillId = 1, RoID = 2 });
        aS.Add(new MediaPlanBillingDetails { BillId = 2, RoID = 3 });
        aS.Add(new MediaPlanBillingDetails { BillId = 2, RoID = 4 });
        aS.Add(new MediaPlanBillingDetails { BillId = 3, RoID = 5 });


        var bs = new List<MediaPlanRo>();
        bs.Add(new MediaPlanRo { RoId = 1 });
        bs.Add(new MediaPlanRo { RoId = 2 });
        bs.Add(new MediaPlanRo { RoId = 3 });
        bs.Add(new MediaPlanRo { RoId = 4 });
        bs.Add(new MediaPlanRo { RoId = 5 });

        var cs = new List<MediaPlanRoDetails>();
        cs.Add(new MediaPlanRoDetails { PrintEstimateId = 1, RoId = 1 });
        cs.Add(new MediaPlanRoDetails { PrintEstimateId = 2, RoId = 1 });
        cs.Add(new MediaPlanRoDetails { PrintEstimateId = 3, RoId = 2 });
        cs.Add(new MediaPlanRoDetails { PrintEstimateId = 4, RoId = 3 });
        cs.Add(new MediaPlanRoDetails { PrintEstimateId = 5, RoId = 4 });
        cs.Add(new MediaPlanRoDetails { PrintEstimateId = 6, RoId = 5 });

        var ds = new List<MediaPlanPrint>();
        ds.Add(new MediaPlanPrint { PrintEstimateId = 1, Amount = 1000 });
        ds.Add(new MediaPlanPrint { PrintEstimateId = 2, Amount = 5000 });
        ds.Add(new MediaPlanPrint { PrintEstimateId = 3, Amount = 6000 });
        ds.Add(new MediaPlanPrint { PrintEstimateId = 4, Amount = 8000 });
        ds.Add(new MediaPlanPrint { PrintEstimateId = 5, Amount = 9000 });
        ds.Add(new MediaPlanPrint { PrintEstimateId = 6, Amount = 10000 });
```

Comment: what do you mean by *to go from MediaPlanBillingDetails to MediaPlanPrint*?

Comment: Means that i can't go directly from table1 to table4. I have to go through them

Comment: Faster than *what*? Hard to say without seeing what the query currently looks like.

Comment: `How to make my linq to entities query for sum faster` <= can you at least post the linq query you have now and illustrate why its slow(er) than you expect?

Comment: As I understand you have to filter `MediaPlanBillingDetails` according to `BillId`, and group accoridng to `RoID ` and find sum of `Amount`. Is this correct?

Comment: This is the query i am currently using .var sumofallbills= MediaPlanBillingDetails.Sum(m => m.MediaPlanRO.MediaPlanROPrints.Sum(qq => qq.MediaPlanPrint.Amount));

Comment: @maztt I've edited that comment into the question. Please keep in mind that you can edit the question instead of adding relevant info as a comment.

Comment: @Adil Mammadov yes that's correct

Comment: If you want a sum of everything (which is what you have now) then why not do `var sumofallbills= MediaPlanPrints.Sum(x => x.Amount);`

Comment: You can use HashSet<T> instead of List<T> - that makes enumeration and aggregation a lot faster with large ienums

Comment: @Igor because the things should be bill wise

Comment: @Shannon Holsinger i will try that

Comment: `because the things should be bill wise` <= I do not understand what that means. Can you add code to illustrate what you are talking about?

Comment: one bill can contain one or multiple roes, one roes can have one or more multiple printestimateids and that's where amount is which i need to sum bill wise. like bill1- 2roes - 1 printestimate ,bill2-1roes -2printestimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have conditions to sum, try to hit over the entity you need to sum, for sample:

```
var result = db.Set<MediaPlanPrint>().Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your models, so we can only estimate that you have all navigation properties. You can try something as below:

```
var result = db.Set<MediaPlanPrint>()
    .Include(m => m.MediaPlanRoDetails) 
    // Filter according to BillId
    .Where(m => m.MediaPlanRoDetails.MediaPlanRo.MediaPlanBillingDetails.BillId < 100)
    // Group by RoId
    .GroupBy(m => m.MediaPlanRoDetails.RoId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        RoId = g.Key,
        TotalAmount = g.Sum(m => m.Amount)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Do the .ToList() only if this is the final query, if not, for example, is better have things as IQueryable<>. Just as a note...